# How can I group values by hour and count the cumulative totals in other columns

Tags: r, grouping

I have a data frame that is aggregated per minute (where one row represents one minute in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format).

I want to group each minute value into their respective hour values/bins.

I have also extracted the hour value from the date field into another column in order to group the data more easily (`YYYY-MM-DD HH`).

I have looked at several approaches/answers where people recommend using `lubridate`/`dplyr`/`anytime` but no approach seems to have worked completely for me.

My data frame:

```
> df

  date                hour                 available busy
1 2018-03-01 01:00:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
2 2018-03-01 01:01:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
3 2018-03-01 01:02:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
4 2018-03-01 01:03:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
5 2018-03-01 01:04:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
6 2018-03-01 01:05:00 2018-03-01 01:00:00  1         1
...
7907 2018-03-14 00:54:00 2018-03-14        1         0
7908 2018-03-14 00:55:00 2018-03-14        1         0
7909 2018-03-14 00:56:00 2018-03-14        2         0
7910 2018-03-14 00:57:00 2018-03-14        1         0
7911 2018-03-14 00:58:00 2018-03-14        1         0
7912 2018-03-14 00:59:00 2018-03-14        1         0
```

I want to group everything by `hour` for each date (I don't mind if I use the `hour` column or whether the values are grouped by the `HH` value in the `date` column) and list the CUMULATIVE number of `available` and `busy` for each hour group.

My desired output df will look like this **(note that these are dummy values and not the actual values)**:

```
  date                    available busy
1 2018-03-01 01:00:00     1         6   
2 2018-03-01 02:00:00     2         11  
3 2018-03-01 03:00:00     10        8 
...
450 2018-03-14 08:00:00   11        1 
451 2018-03-14 09:00:00   24        19
452 2018-03-14 10:00:00   12        4
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more clarity as to the logic behind the cumulative sums? For instance, why for time `01:00:00` and the start of `df` does `busy` sum to 6 but `available` sums to 1?

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(head(df, 50))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the sample data:

[image]

Here's the `dplyr` code to do that:

```
library(lubridate)
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>%
  summarize(
    available = sum(available),
    busy = sum(available)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```